# Jquery - Where can I find an image fader / all other images fading out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, transparency, photo-gallery

I've been searching for a JQuery based image "fader" and not too sure what to look for.

It would start with a series of thumbnail images that are all 100% solid. When you hover over a selected image, all the others turn semi transparent (or in some cases black and white)

I've seen this sort of plugin before, but I'm not sure what it's called!

Could someone suggest a script or what these sorts of plugins are known as please.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need plugin for that.

```
//fade out all images
$('img').animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! What would be better .animate or .fadeto?

Comment: Irelevant. Functionally the same, but probably fadeTo() is a bit shorter.